# R function scope related

Tags: r

I basically want to write separate files for a project in R.

I created a file named rsqData.r & its contents are:

```
rsqData <- modules::module({
  get_rsq_data <- function () {
    d <- read.csv("/home/xxx/test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ',')
  }
})
```

I have a wrapper script (wrapper.r) that "use"s this, like this:

```
library(modules)
m <- use("utils/rsqData.r")
m$rsqData$get_rsq_data()
```

When I run, `R -f wrapper.r` I get this error:

```
Error in m$rsqData$get_rsq_data() : could not find function "read.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
rsqData <- modules::module({
  get_rsq_data <- function () {
    d <- utils:::read.csv("/home/xxx/test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ',')
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks that works. is there any explanation for using ':::' there?

Comment: read.csv is from utils package, ':::' specifies that a function belongs to that package

Comment: the two colons should work, why specify three colons?

Comment: In this case two is good enough, some packages require three like SparkR.